I want to place logo at left top side, but It appears below than location of design page. (XML, Kotlin)
I'm student. and I'm making school app for my coding club. I want to place my school logo at left top side. In design view, there is no problem.

But when I open app in android, The location of logo is lower than it appears in the design window.

and I removed title bar, is there any connect with this problem?
there is my xml code.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.Mainpage.Mainpage">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_mainpage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hongcheon"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/hongcheon"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I changed many attribute and padding, but I couldn't solve this problem. how to solve it?
I guess that the logo places to be placed below the title bar.
